# What is the mysqli equivalent to this?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

It seems I'm a little old school when it comes to php/mysql and to be honest only just getting used to it but now I keep getting told to use **mysqli** rather then **mysql** so I been I've reading a few posts/articles and such including php.net about it but none of it is making sense to me so thought maybe if some would give me an equivalent to my snippet I might start to get an understanding of it a little better...

This is a simple mysql while loop:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 10";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$dog = $row['dog'];

  echo $dog;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent using `mysqli` in a procedural style would be:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 10";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
    $dog = $row['dog'];
    echo $dog;
}

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Can the connect to db line be put in a config file so it can be called from any page using `include('config.php');` or is it suppost to be called each time you need to use it?

Comment: It can be put in another file to be called any time you need it. Just remember if you're returning a result set to free it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 10";
$result = mysqli_query($query) or die (mysqli_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

$dog = $row['dog'];

  echo $dog;

}
```

Comment: So far it looks like just changing mysql to mysqli but I know It can't be that simple, everything I have read seems to use `::` and `new`

Comment: @AnnaRiekic Those indicate that they are using place holders. They act as a way to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli has two different interfaces, one very similar to the old-style mysql interface and an object-oriented one.

The object-oriented version works like that:

```
/* establish connection */
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo $mysqli->connect_error;
    return;
}

/* query & fetch-loop */
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10, 10");
if (!$result) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    return;
}
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $dog = $row['dog'];
    echo $dog;
}
```

As you can see, the code length is about the same as the old style version (just ignore the error-checking and the opening of the connection).

BTW: The mysqli documentation isn't too bad, you just need to skip the 1st page, as this one is really weird. I would start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php.